# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined (even if no discord.js API call)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I created a long time ago a Discord bot using node discord.js. Since some weeks, it started to crash randomly between ten minutes and some hours after I start the node.
In case of the discord.js API changed, I reduced the bot code to the minimal, but it still crashes with the same error (see code and error below).

Does someone please have an idea of what my be the problem?

I'm using node version 16.13.1 and discord.js 14.6.0, running on a Synology NAS 216+.

Bot code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

var prefix = "!";
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 99;

client.login("XXX");

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("I'm on!"); // this effectively prints in console when node starts
});
```

Error message:

```
/volume1/homes/bots/Bot discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:11
const existing = channel.messages.cache.get(data.id);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
at MessageCreateAction.handle (/volume1/homes/bots/Bot discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:11:41)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/volume1/homes/bots/Bot discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/volume1/homes/bots/Bot discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSoc ketManag er.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/volume1/homes/bots/Bot discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/volume1/homes/bots/Bot discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/volume1/homes/bots/Bot discord/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/volume1/homes/bots/Bot discord/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:797:20)
at Receiver.emit (events.js:314:20)
at Receiver.dataMessage (/volume1/homes/bots/Bot discord/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:437:14)
```

Thanks a lot!
Regards.

Comment: You should probably update the library

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunatly, I already did that. I updated 1. My NAS system, 2. node.js (which was in version 12) and discord.js. That did not correct the error.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? Since I think v13 the client constructor has required an intents option to construct the class.

Comment: v14, That might explain why the problem appeared out of nowhere. I'll check the new client constructor requirement then, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use discord.js v14 you need to have node.js v17+ installed.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that! It's just a bit strange though since I used npm install on node.js v16 to have discord.js v14, guess it's not selecting the right version by default.

Answer (score 0):

Bec u are using discord.js v14.6, Try reinstalling the nodejs to v19.0.0 and delete the node modules and reinstall it again by doing

`npm i`

This will automatically install the node modules that you mentioned on every require() function

Comment: Thanks, I'll try updating node.js then!